# Integrate Dropbox into Windows' save dialog

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, dropbox

In Windows 8.1 there is SkyDrive showing in the save dialog.

[image]

How do I make my Dropbox folder show here for easy access? I noticed that these elements are the main groups on the left in `This PC` window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add dropbox to your places bar. [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/97824/) shows how you can accomplish this through the registry, or even using a Placesbar Editor.

Comment: This way it goes quite down in the list because dr is not the first in alphabets.

Comment: Change the View Settings to a **list** view.

Comment: That doesn't change it. Those that are showing in the picture in my question are still first, followed by folders and the files in alphabetical order (including shortcuts).

Comment: Maybe if you added dropbox to your places bar? [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/97824/) shows you can accomplish this through the Registry.

Comment: @nonterrorist Changing the registry works great. The "Placesbar editor" works even easier. You'll have 5 spots to fill the bar but i guess if you use Dropbox enough you can loose "Network" or "Recent places". You might want to consider putting this in your answer because i don't think there is another possibility (if you want it in the left-bar).

Answer (score 0):

Just add Dropbox as a library. Takes 30 seconds and is much easier than the registry solution. Instrutions here: http://www.ghacks.net/2011/12/07/add-dropbox-as-a-library-to-windows-7/ (works the same way for Win 8)

Comment: Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).